# pandas - how to ensure data frame is local

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Suppose I have a function that operates on a generic dataframe say:

```
def myfunc(df1, ...):
    ...
    df1.loc[:,myCol] = x # some manipulations inside myfunc
    ...
    return df1
```

Now, suppose I have multiple data frames outside the function, say `df1`, `df2`, `df3` on which I want to apply `myfunc`. I want to ensure that the function `myfunc` uses a local copy of the dataframe - I want to avoid the situation that the `df1` outside the function doesn't get changed / modified by the operations inside the dataframe.

(i) How can I ensure that the `df1` used in `myfunc` doesn't refer to `df1` outside the function?

(ii) For instance, I tried to redesign the module as

```
def myfunc(df1, ...):
    df2 = df1.copy(deep = True)
    ...
    df2.loc[:,myCol] = x # some manipulations inside myfunc
    ...
    return df2
```

but even in this case, I have to always remember not to use `df2` to define a dataframe out the function (lest it gets modified in the `myfunc`).

Any alternatives?

Comment: does `myfunc` really modify the outer `df2`? doesn't this break python variable scoping rules? Could you not just rename the function variable to `local_df` or `temp_var_df` or similar?

Comment: Yes, it can modify. I need to remember never to use `local_df` or `temp_var_df`. I kind of like your suggestion to use the `local` word to help me remember never to use it outside a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm.... I'm not sure how it would modify the namespace per your comments:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2]})

def myfunc2(df1):
    df1 = df1.copy(deep=True)
    df1.loc[:, 'a'] = 10
    return df1

>>> df1
   a
0  1
1  2

>>> myfunc2(df1)
    a
0  10
1  10

>>> df1
   a
0  1
1  2
```

df1 is the same before and after the function call.